# Describing controller query parameters in PHPDoc

Tags: php, laravel, phpdoc

My Laravel controller has an index method on it which accepts an optional query string parameter.

How should this be represented in the method's PHPDoc block?

EmployerController.php:

```
/**
 * @param Request $request
 * @return Response
 * Returns list of Employers
 */
public function index(Request $request) {
    // This is the optional parameter which needs to be represented
    // in the PHPDoc block
    $collectiveAgreement = $request->query('collective_agreement');

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your purpose is to document those fields, I'd recommend to create a FormRequest that handles all that logic, and then inject the form request into the controller. This way, you know where the request is formed and then go to that class to see the fields and even better: the rules for them to pass the validation.

```
php artisan make:request ListUsersRequest
```

#### ListUsersRequest.php

```
namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class ListUsersRequest extends FormRequest {

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'collective_agreement' => ['here', 'goes', 'your', 'rules'],
            'another_field'        => ['here', 'goes', 'more', 'rules'],
        ];
    }

    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Then, back to your controller

#### UserController.php

```
public function index(ListUsersRequest $request)
{   //                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    $data = $request->validated();
    $collectiveAgreement = $data['collective_agreement'];
//  Or as you did:   
//  $collectiveAgreement = $request->query('collective_agreement');
}
```

Comment: I think this is the correct answer, the only downside is it makes the code a bit more verbose than it really deserves to be. Do you have links to any solid examples/docs which implement your suggestion?

Comment: @KennyHorna is correct. This is a better way to document your api. It means if there's any need to change those 'optional' parameters in the future, you end up doing it once i.e the logic is changed and the doc is changed at the same Request class. Moreover, doc-block documentation can easily get outdated soon when logic changes.

Answer (score 0):

Keep description in first line and `@param` and `@return` under that. It would be sort of standard order. Feel free to add description as you would like and how it would help other who read the code. In this case you've already documented param since that query string is part of `$request` object but you can extend description to be like:

```
/**
 * Returns list of Employers. 
 * Request object may have optional query string parameter 'collective_agreement'
 * used for this and this and that and that
 *
 * @param Request $request
 * @return Response
 */
public function index(Request $request)
{
    // This is the optional parameter which needs to be represented
    // in the PHPDoc block
    $collectiveAgreement = $request->query('collective_agreement');
    ...
}
```

Comment: Technically correct, but I think Kenny Horna's answer is the one I'm after even though it requires a code change.