# Attributes for Symfony route

Tags: symfony, routes, php-attributes

In Symfony controllers, route are defined as follow :

```
class BlogController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('/blog/{page}', name: 'blog_list', requirements: ['page' => '\d+'])]
    public function list(int $page): Response
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Imagine now, you have a request or query parameter in this url. There's no functional need to define it in the route, it is accessible through `$request->get('parameter_name')`.

```
class BlogController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('/blog/{page}', name: 'blog_list', requirements: ['page' => '\d+'])]
    public function list(Request $request, int $page): Response
    {
        $id = $request->get('id');
    }
}
```

But I'm wondering if it is not more clear to define this parameter as attribute. For exemple like this :

```
class BlogController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('/blog/{page}', name: 'blog_list', requirements: ['page' => '\d+', 'id' => '\d+'])]
    public function list(Request $request, int $page): Response
    {
        $id = $request->get('id');
    }
}
```

But in that case, Symfony won't check the type of the attribute (ie, url like /blog/1?id="foo" will work).

So maybe something like this with annotations

```
class BlogController extends AbstractController
    {
        
    /**
     * @param int id Id of the post to be highlighted
     */
    #[Route('/blog/{page}', name: 'blog_list', requirements: ['page' => '\d+', 'id' => '\d+'])]
        public function list(Request $request, int $page): Response
        {
            $id = $request->get('id');
        }
    }
}
```

Or maybe as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61220073/describing-controller-query-parameters-in-phpdoc) for Laravel :

```
class BlogController extends AbstractController
    {
        
   /**
    * Returns list of posts. 
    * Request object may have optional query int parameter 'id'
    * used for highlighting a specific post
    *
    * @param Request $request
    * @return Response
    */
    #[Route('/blog/{page}', name: 'blog_list', requirements: ['page' => '\d+', 'id' => '\d+'])]
        public function list(Request $request, int $page): Response
        {
            $id = $request->get('id');
        }
    }
}
```

So what is the best option for a clear and well documented code ?

Comment: check the docs, the annotations should look little different like the ones u supplied https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#creating-routes-as-attributes-or-annotations

Comment: e.g you dont want to mix route-parameters with query parameters as they are not the same `The query string of a URL is not considered when matching routes.` For documenting/commenting your code just use DocBloc comment standard https://pear.php.net/manual/en/standards.sample.php

Comment: Bit off topic perhaps but `$request->query->get('id')` would have made it clear where id was coming from.  But as you say, no validation or type checking.  That is up to you.

Comment: What happen if you make: #[Route('/blog/{page}', name: 'blog_list', requirements: ['page' => '\d+'], condition: "params['id'] > 0")]

Answer (score -2):

I was searching this question as well. There is no way illustrating params and return types throug attributes. I think mixing annotations and attributes is ok for now. May be it will be available in later versions of php